# Qual é mais rápido? Buscar dado no Banco ou lendo um cookie?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework

Galera, na opinião de vocês, o que seria melhor nesta situação?

Estou trabahando em um site Asp MVC e Entity Framework.
Tenho uma tabela de unidades federativas onde tenho (simplificando) 3 colunas Id, NomeEstado, UrlEstado. Exemplo: 1, Minas Gerais, minasgerais.

Há uma busca por estados, onde o usuário seleciona o estado em um listbox e envia a requisição, contendo o Id do Estado para uma Action de roteamento Busca.

Se essa action receber outros dados por exemplo uma cidade, vai redirecionar para a action que retorna a url com a cidade MeuSite/Estado/Cidade.

Se receber apenas o estado (o caso que nos interessa aqui) será redirecionado para a action que retorna a url com apenas o estado, por exemplo: MeuSite/minasgerais

Simples, certo?

A assinatura (simplificada) dessas actions seria:

```
public ActionResult Busca(int estado = 0, int cidade = 0 ...)
public ActionResult Estado(string urlEstado)
```

Mas perceba que eu recebo um id. E ao encaminhar a action pede uma string com a url. Até porque se não a url ficaria MeuSite/1 o que não é amigável. Então busco a url no banco e redirecino. Ok.

Mas aí na action do estado vou precisar do Id desse estado. Então vem a minha dúvida. Seria mais rápido em termos de desempeno para o site, buscar o Id no banco de dados pela url (que também é única). Ou ler um cookie gravado na action Busca contendo apenas o id?

Faço a leitura do cookie assim:

```
HttpCookie Cookie = Request.Cookies[Nome];
return Server.UrlDecode(Cookie.Values.Get(chaveValoresCookie));
```

E lendo do banco seria:

```
int id = ctx.tbEstado.where(e => e.Url == url).select(e => e.Id).FirstOrDefalt();
```

Comment: Ler o cookie seria mais rápido porque vem com a própria requisição, não precisas aceder a outro recurso

Comment: Obrigado Miguel.Acho a pergunta meio boba, mas como nunca trabalhei com cookies, talvez a resposta me surpreendesse.

Comment: da uma olhada no node.js ele ajuda muito nesse tipo de necessidade, já que é um db json, o cookie pode até te ajudar nessa situação, mas não é recomendado usar cookie para isso, cookie é para coisas pequenas, objetos e listas é melhor colocar em outro local.